# Put Syntax at the top of Documentation Pages

Tags: discussion, documentation

I was looking through some of the documentation, speificaly `JavaScript >> Arrays` [located here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/187/arrays#t=201608250424108868562).

There is some awesome information here, and just reading through it will introduce a lot of people to things they never knew existed.

**But** think of a beginner javascript developer or student.  They visit the page and the first thing they see is how to convert a list to an array.  Shouldn't the first thing on the Arrays page be:

1. How to create an Array
2. How to add an element to an Array
3. How to remove an element from an Array

These ***essentials*** fit perfectly in the syntax area of documentation.  But the fact that it is located at the bottom of the page is quite silly.